# My init script not showing up in service autocomplete

Tags: bash, service

I made a init script for a ghost website.  I'm using Linux Mint 16 (aka Ubuntu 13.10)

When I type this, my script doesn't show up in autocomplete.

```
sudo service f<tab>
```

Any reason why?  I get a different script "friendly_recover", but not mine.

Thanks!

Mike

/etc/init/furtheryet.org.conf

```
# furtheryet.org

start on startup

script
    cd /var/www/furtheryet.org/ghost
    npm start --production
end script
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you expect that `sudo service f<tab>` will auto-complete with `sudo service furtheryet.org.conf` ?

No, it will not, because :

- it is just a config file
- it is located in the wrong directory for that

You should consider the `/etc/init.d` folder :

- The `/etc/init/` folder only contains configuration files used by
  `Upstart`.
- The `/etc/init.d` folder contains shell scripts that respond to
  `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `reload` (and whatwever you could
  implement).

Further reading : https://askubuntu.com/questions/5039/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-init-and-etc-init-d

That said, to make your script auto-complete, you should at least put it in the `/etc/init.d` folder, and make it executable.

But your script is actually just a config file. You should consider writing a specific [service/init script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot) and put it in your `/etc/init.d` folder.

---

In some cases i've notice that even if the script is located in `/etc/init.d` you may have issues with auto-complete on `Ubuntu 13.10` as `root` user.

To correct this, as root user, edit `$HOME/.bachrc` file and uncomment the following :

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Then reload your `.bashrc` file by running : `. $HOME/.bashrc`

Comment: Ah, ok.  There is also a "friendly-recovery" script in init.d

"sudo service furtheryet.org starts", it just doesn't autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I reached it through Google, and the selected answer is wrong.

Upstart jobs have to be placed to `/etc/init` folder.

Every package that provides a standard daemon using upstart is required to provide a symlink in /etc/init.d by Debian policy.

Then, autocompletion for sudo service name will work.

There are special upstart jobs in /etc/init that do not have a corresponding entry in /etc/init.d. These are an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the same directory type `./f` then hit `<tab>`. Otherwise you have to type: `/etc/init/f` before you hit `<tab>`.

And your script has to be executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/init/furtheryet.org.conf
```